# NHibernate custom projection with Less than or Equal to

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am trying to create a projection which will filter results from the database using the Levenshtein search distance calculation.  To create this I open a session to the DB and then use `CreateCriteria` to query the database:

```
...
return session.CreateCriteria<Contact>()
              .Add(Expression.Le(Levenshtein("FullName", "Bob"), 5)
...
```

Created a small helper method to return a new instance of the projection class

```
public static LevenshteinProjection Levenshtein(string propertyName, string searchValue)
{
    return new LevenshteinProjection(propertyName, searchValue);
}
```

Essentially everything works fine when creating the string to compile the text but when I look at the SQL that is produced the value I want to be less than or equal to is a `?`!

```
... {rest of sql select} WHERE levenshtein(this_.full_name, 'Bob') <= ?
```

Why is it adding the ?  I've set the return type to

```
public override IType[] GetTypes(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
{
    return new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 };
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ? represents the parameter placeholder.

NHibernate generates a 'parameterized query'.  Instead of creating a query with the parameter-value hardcoded, it generates a query that contains a parameter.
The parameter will be assigned with the value that you provide.

This enables the DBMS to cache query execution plans.

Comment: In which case, why is it not filtering the data?

Comment: Never mind, I am being stupid but looking into this did improve my sql as I added the second value in the levenshtien as a parameter.  I used ShowSql in the connection string which showed the parameters actually being passed (and running the sql yielded the same result).

Comment: Also, I need to learn the difference between <= and >= *slams head against desk in disappointment*